# expect (js) not working inside superagent (js)

Tags: node.js, superagent, expect.js

I'm trying to do TDD for the Rest APIs that I've been creating. New to NodeJS.

I've created a Rest API, and on the response I want to perform all the `expect` checks. To make an HTTP request I'm using `SuperagentJS` (also tried `RequestJS`).

Here is how my code looks like (Snippet only, not whole code)

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var request = require("superagent");

describe("Creation of New Entity", function(){
    it("Create a New Entity", function(){
        request
            .get("http://localhost")
            .end(function(err, httpResponse){
                expect("1234").to.have.length(3);//equals(500);
                expect(200).to.equals(200);
        });
    });
});
```

No matter what I try, mocha always gives successful result. (All test cases passed)

Please tell what I'm missing here. What should I do to implement test cases on `httpRespnse`. I'm sure that request is working fine, because whenever I use `console.log(httpResponse.text)`, it is returning the default apache home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All networking in node.js is asynchronous, therefore you must use the mocha asynchronous flavor of `it("Create a New Entity", function(done) {` and call the `done` callback when your test is done.

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var request = require("superagent");

describe("Creation of New Entity", function(){
    it("Create a New Entity", function(done){
        request
            .get("http://localhost")
            .end(function(err, httpResponse){
                expect(err).not.to.exist();
                expect("1234").to.have.length(3);//equals(500);
                expect(200).to.equals(200);
                done()
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, need to learn a lot about how async node work. Any references you can suggest?

Comment: [The learnyounode nodeschool workshop](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode) is a good place to start.